# Integrating issue of G729 with latest version of PJSIP for android

Tags: android, codec, pjsip, g729

I want to integrate G729 codec with PJSIP for android. For this purpose, i found two kind of solution.

1) Intel IPP_Codecs which are specified on PJSIP website: [Attached_URL](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Intel_IPP_Codecs#LinuxInstructions)

2) Patches from Csipsimple or Linphone

**For Intel IPP_Codecs :**  I have followed following tutorial : 
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Intel_IPP_Codecs#LinuxInstructions

After following the tutorial, i figured out  that Intel have no longer support of ARM base architecture and G729 sample code is also no longer provided by Intel in latest release of Intel IPP library. So i am unable to integrate  Intel IPP Codecs with PJSIP.

**Secondly patches are available till  PJSIP 2.5v and many of these tutorial cannot resolved my problem.**

So please guide me how should  i integrate G729 codecs with latest version of PJSIP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that IPP is only for intel CPU's and you also have to pay for it.

Have you tried [this patch](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder).

Even if the patch files don't work, look at what the [g729 part of the patch](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder/tree/master/g729_patch) is doing and add the changes in manually.  If you follow what it's doing then it's not too hard to add in.

Just remember if you do use this patch you are meant to [pay](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+G.729+Licensing) for the g729 license.

Comment: Thanks man. I already followed mentioned tutorial and successfully integrate G729 Codec with PJSIP.